# What shades of blue go well together (website design)

Tags: website-design, color

I've got a fixed layout page and the client has asked for it to have "shades of blue". What colour would you recommend for the background, page wrapper background, text, dropdown menu and the buttons on the side?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, and the answer really depends upon the actual brief. What feel should the site have, for what kind of company is it, etc. If you want to know more about the value of colour in your webdesign, and how to make your own palettes, I recommend http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/28/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/ and its two sequels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blue is a really diverse color. I suppose they all are, but 'blue' can mean anything from cyan all the way to indigo. There's a lot in between.

Ideally, it's good to pick colors for a reason; @Bakabaka's link in his comment gives some insight into color theory and the psychology of color. If your client has a logo or brand, it'd be really smart to pick blues that complement the brand's color scheme.

But if it's just a matter of picking nice shades of blue, then I find it's nice to use a site like [COLOURlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/palettes/search?sortCol=votes&sortBy=desc&publishedEndDate=01%2F23%2F2013&publishedBeginDate=12%2F27%2F2004&query=&userName=&hex=&hueOptions%5b0%5d=blue&hueOptions%5b1%5d=blueviolet&hueOptions%5b2%5d=skyblue&x=106&y=11) - you'll see that this link searches for palettes that contain different kinds of blue. Adobe's [Kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/#themes/search?term=blues) gets you some nice palettes as well.

Comment: Thank you!
If you don't mind, are you able to critique the colour theme and font sizes, font type and margins and paddings of my prototype website I'm currently building?
http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/39/90555971.jpg